# Execute Powe shell Command From VSTS Build Task Code

Tags: typescript, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I need to execute `##vso[task.addattachment]value` power shell command from my VSTS extension code to attach a data file to build result. I'm using TypeScript to develop the build task. Please share any dev sample codes to achieve this using vss-task library.

Comment: The command must be ran in a build process, is your extension a build task?

Comment: @Eddie, Yes, Its a build task. Will it work if I execute following?
'console.log("##vso[task.addattachment type=attype;name=summarypagedata;]c:/myfolder/summarydata.txt");'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just as I indicated in your previous question, you just need to write out the command to build console during the build process. For Typescript, you can use console.log() command to do this.

Comment: Thanks Eddie, I have managed to attache the file using below command from typescript.

console.log("##vso[task.addattachment type=myAttachmentType;name=myAttachmentName;]c:/myfolder/myData.txt");